# Visual Studio 2019: Disable auto formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I am trying to disable two very annoying things, but I can’t achieve that. I am using VS to edit C# code for Unity.

1. When I make a tab indentation, it randomly replaces it with 4 spaces. So in 80% of the cases, when I want to remove the last line, I have to hit delete 4 times for each indentation. That doesn’t make sense and I just never want spaces as indentations.
2. When I write void SomeFunction(){ and then hit }, it makes a space between { and }. I don’t know why, and I don’t know how to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Tabs | Check "Keep Tabs"
2. If you like to you can disable automatically formating, or try to change formatting to your liking in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style

Comment: Thanks for your answer, somehow my settings look different from others (apart from being German):

https://ibb.co/k95K18D

Comment: You are using Visual Studio for Mac, I don't where the settings are, or if there are settings  at all on Visual Studio for Mac. - Visual Studio and Visual Studio for Mac aren't 100% the same.